# Can`t get ALL my instagram followers list even with pagination

Tags: api, pagination, instagram

i`m using this link to get my followers list usernames

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=XXXXXX
```

it returns 50 users with a pagination url for the next 50

the problem is the pagination url will stop showing after i reach 245 users, i do have more than 300.

when i tried to get a list os followers of another user thats not mine and its a public user with more than 600 followers i managed to get al the list

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by?access_token=XXXXXX
```

so i said maybe i should change the request link and replace `self` with my userid because thats the only different between the two requests BUT still getting the same result, only 245.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{my-user-id}/followed-by?access_token=XXXXXX
```

so is there another way to get all my followers usernames ? or Instagram is limiting this endpoint ?

thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**

I even tried to add `&count=-1` and it does not work
Tried `&count=100` , `&count=300` and still showing only to 245 users

Comment: Are you keeping the actual list of users from each call. I have noticed that the calls don't always return 50 users, sometimes it can be more.

Comment: @OnlyJoe Of couse i'm, and yes sometime it gets less than 50 and sometimes up to 100 if you added &count=100

Comment: @aLFaRSi Hello , I am facing same issues. Have you got answer ? If yes, then can you please share it . Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Kanchan No not yet sorry man

Comment: Faced same problem with `follows` also; very very strange return values, but think I got smth wrong with my hands.

Comment: There is an interesting post, I found few hours ago: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/Lr1Sx5lRuIs